# no init found. Try passing init = bootarg in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I have tried many options, but so far none was the solution.

I booted the PC using Ubuntu LiveCD.

Then in terminal, i ran the command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

It showed all the disk details. Then i ran this command:

```
sudo fsck -y/dev/sda1
```

The output was:

```
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
```

Then i restarted the system again, and the message prompted was: "no init found. Try passing init = bootarg" (initramfs):

Please help me out i have important data in this system.

Comment: What FS do you use for your file system

Answer (score 0):

The system is likely broken. Unfortunately, I (and most other people) can't help you recover the system with the information provided so far. However, I can help you retreive your data. Boot the livecd. Mount the drive (it will be detected as something like "100500TB File System", the size may differ). Grab all the data you need, back it up elsewhere (removable HD, usb stick, CD/DVD/BRD, depends on the data size). Then reinstall.

Comment: while trying to mount the drive it shows error "unable to mount location--- DBus error Org.gtk.private.remoteVolumeMonitor.faile:An operation is already pending."